# Multiple KafkaListener / One topic

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 2.2.12, and I just begin.

I want to manage creation/update of business entities througt kafka. If possible, in the same topic, to guarantee the order (by providing a business key). As this is not the same java types (creation and request), I think I need to have 2 KafkaListener (with their own ContainerFactory / JsonDeserializer). Maybe I'm wrong?

So my question is: is it possible, to have differents KafkaListener (because of deserialization) which consume the same topic (to conserve the order of messages) ?

Maybe i'm not approaching the subject in the right way... I have not managed to use different objects types in one KafkaListener.

Thanks you.

Comment: Can I use the JsonDeserializer<T> if different types are possible ?!

Answer (score 0):

If the producer is Spring too, and uses the `JsonSerializer`; it will add type information in headers (by default), used by the `JsonDeserializer` to create the target object.

If the types are different (source and destination), but type-compatible from a JSON perspective, you can add type mapping information to the deserializer.

The type mapping can also be used if the source is not Spring (but can be modified to set the type information headers).

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#json).

You can also use the [`Delegating` serializer/deserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#delegating-serialization) to invoke different implementations based on some header.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the producer is Spring too. But I need to provide a class to the constructor of JsonDeserializer. It's the point that I don't understand. In my case, I want with one JsonDeserializer, be able to deserialize differents types. JsonDeserializer seems to be necessary typed..

Comment: `>But I need to provide a class to the constructor of JsonDeserializer.` Only if the producer is not Spring; by default, the deserializer will use the type headers and only fall-back to using the supplied class when there is no header. See `setUseTypeHeaders()` (default true).

Comment: I was focused on the constructor DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, Serializer, Deserializer)... I didn't see the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config). Perfect. Thanks you.

Comment: Another think, If I don't provide any deserializer, my json deserialization failed because my class is not in the trusted package. The method addTrustedPackage exists only in the JsonDeserializer... but my goal is to not instanciate this one because I don't know the target class. How can I do?

Comment: Ok, we can provide a deserializer configuration at the consumerFactory level :         props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

Comment: That's ok, as long as you trust the message producer; this mechanism is to protect against malicious actors.